# Inserting array into table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I am trying to insert data from array to mysql table. If I have for example in array three items, the result of echo is Item1Item2Item3 but in the mysql table is inserted only Item3. Why it dont repeat inserting into table?

```
<?php
session_start();
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $item){
    $sql="INSERT INTO eshopadmin (Item)
          VALUES
          ('$item[item]')";
    echo $item[item];
}
?>
```

Comment: this will generate the N+1 issue try inserting all the values at once.using one query.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    $data; //array that will store all the data
    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $item){
      // push data to the array
      array_push($data,$item[item]);

      $data= implode(",", $data);
    }
       $sql="INSERT INTO eshopadmin (Item)
              VALUES
              ('$data')";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Very common practise to use [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) and [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) for retrieving arrays to and from a database table field.

```php
$array = array('a','b','c');
$sql = 'INSERT INTO eshopadmin (Item) VALUES ("'.implode(',', $array).'")';
```

the array is stored as `a,b,c`

and when retrieving it :

```php
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$array = explode(',', $row['Item']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use prepared statements as well. I'm used to MySQLi.

```php
<?php
// loop only if cart is array and has items
if( is_array( $_SESSION['cart'] ) && count( $_SESSION['cart'] ) ){
    // autocommit off
    $mysqli_instance->autocommit( false );
    // prepare insert sql
    $insert_statement = $mysqli_instance->prepare( '
        INSERT INTO eshopadmin
            ( Item )
        VALUES
            ( ? )
    ' );
    // bind variables to the statement
    $insert_statement->bind_param( 'i', $item_array_item_value );
    // loop throught array
    foreach( $_SESSION['cart'] as $item ){
        $item_array_item_value = $item['item'];
        $insert_statement->execute();
    }
    // manually commit
    $mysqli_instance->commit();
    // restore autocommit
    $mysqli_instance->autocommit( true );
}
```

PS: I just realized it's a really old post. Don't know why was it listed in the latest feed.